# how do i turn any text based formula "f(x)=ex-3x" or "f(x)=ex-sinx" into a functioning formula given that x is defined is located at a specific cell

Tags: excel, vba

'if my x is located at A1'
f(x)=ex-3x 'turn into' =exp(a1)-3*(a1)
f(x)=ex-sinx 'turn into' =exp(a1)-sin(a1)

Answer (score -1):

I hope this gets you started:

```
Option Explicit

Sub sub1()
  Dim x!, fx1!, fx2!
  x = Range("a1").Value
  ' or
  x = Cells(1, 1)
  fx1 = exp(x) - 3 * x
  fx2 = exp(x) - Sin(x)
  MsgBox "fx1=" & fx1 & vbCrLf & "fx2=" & fx2
End Sub
```